# JavaScript is acting suddenly unexpected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, timeout

I have used successfully over long time the below JavaScript function in my theme options page.
It does save the WP Theme Options by JavaScript and puts a message on my screen once saved.

Suddenly, if I change the timeout settings (value) the message does either not show at all, or does show but does not hide anymore.

This is my JavaScript:

```
<!--Include AJAX save message + styles-->
<div id="saveResult"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#myOptionsForm').submit(function() { 
      jQuery(this).ajaxSubmit({
        success: function(){
          jQuery('#saveResult').html("<div id='saveMessage'class='successModal'></div>");
          jQuery('#saveMessage').append("<p><?php echo htmlentities(__('Settings Saved Successfully','wp'),ENT_QUOTES); ?></p>").show();
        }, timeout: 5000
      }); 
      setTimeout("jQuery('#saveMessage').hide('slow');", 5000);
      return false; 
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is the according CSS:

```
.successModal {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  left: 20%;
  border-radius: 50% !important;;
  width: 123px;
  height: 153px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  background-image: url("Smile-success.png");
  z-index:1002;
  overflow: auto;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #cfcfcf;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #cfcfcf;
}
```

This all worked very good until I uploaded the entire theme to GitHub, and then back down to my Computer.

Since then, not even a MAC Time Capsule Backup solves the problem.

The problem, if I change the timeout: 5000 to (which before was possible) 
timeout: 2000 or any other value, 
the message des not disappear any more and takes very long to show up.

Does any body have a idea what this could be?

I tried even a scratch version of options page.

What can be the issue for it stop work all of a sudden, even browser crossing?

I tried also MAMP Restar, fresh folders, fresh instal...

I really hope somebody can help me put here :)

Answer (score 3):

Try changing `setTimeout("jQuery('#saveMessage').hide('slow');", 5000);` to `setTimeout(function() { jQuery('#saveMessage').hide('slow'); }, 5000);`

Comment: this brought back the message! 
but still, i can not anymore change the "time set":
If I do:

setTimeout(function() { jQuery('#saveMessage').hide('slow'); }, 2000);

the message shows up but does not disappear anymore.

If I do:

timeout: 2000
  }); 
 setTimeout(function() { jQuery('#saveMessage').hide('slow'); }, 5000);

the message does not even appear

Same if I do
timeout: 2000
  }); 
  setTimeout(function() { jQuery('#saveMessage').hide('slow'); }, 2000);
I could change it previously to 50000  to edit CSS with firefox console...) .. I am puzzled

Comment: @beda69 So you are telling me the timeout only works when it's 5000?

Comment: @beda69 Might sound stupid, but are you changing the 5000 in **both places**?

Comment: i was previously able to just change it in first place (up to 50'000 to keep it long enough visible, so to edit in CSS editor)
Now, if I change either both, only first, only second, no matters which, it works only if both values are set to 5000
and that was not so, previously, definitely :)
I am developing since 3 months now. 
This happened after upload - download from git.
I am very at end of latin :)

Comment: my goal, actually, is to show the message ASAP and let it visible for perhaps 3 sec- max.
previously, I could change whatever I wanted in timout: ... 
now, I can't change a thing !

Comment: @beda69 I'll rewrite your code. I don't understand how Git could make such changes.

Comment: StackOverflow wants me to proceed this on the Chat,, but i haven't enough reputation.
I have already fully rewritten the code. It' not working anymore as before.
Guess I have to look for new solutions... ?